# Invalid column name error in SQL Server after adding new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

First the solution is working perfect, and after as per our Project Manager requirement I have added two column in table. After that one **insert,update** store procedure is not working it show "Invalid column name" (it mention newly inserted two column name). I think some details is stored in temporary but I don't know how to find and solve it.

I tried something like this:

- Removed all constrain and tried to run the store procedure, but no use
- Just removed the newly added two column, it is working perfect.
- Tried to add the column through an `Alter` query

My stored procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Page].[SP_INSERT_EXPERIENCEDETAILS]
    (@EXPERIENCEDETAILS [PAGE].[EXPERIENCEDETAILS] READONLY)
AS  --drop  PROCEDURE [Page].[SP_INSERT_EXPERIENCEDETAILS]
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TEMPTABLE AS TABLE
                           (
                              ID INT,
                              [ACTION] VARCHAR(50)
                           )

    MERGE INTO [PAGE].[EXPERIENCEDETAILS] AS TARGET
    USING (SELECT 
               ID, Description, ISCurrent, COMPANYID,
               Designationid, locationid, FROMDAY, FromMonth, FromYear,
               TODAY, TOMONTH, Toyear 
           FROM 
               @EXPERIENCEDETAILS) AS SOURCE ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID 

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE
           SET TARGET.[DESCRIPTION] = SOURCE.[DESCRIPTION],
               TARGET.ISCURRENT = SOURCE.ISCURRENT,
               TARGET.COMPANYID = SOURCE.COMPANYID,
               TARGET.DESIGNATIONID = SOURCE.DESIGNATIONID,
               TARGET.LOCATIONID = SOURCE.LOCATIONID,
               TARGET.FROMDAY = SOURCE.FROMDAY,
               TARGET.FROMMONTH = SOURCE.FROMMONTH,
               TARGET.FROMYEAR = SOURCE.FROMYEAR,
               TARGET.TODAY = SOURCE.TODAY,
               TARGET.TOMONTH = SOURCE.TOMONTH,
               TARGET.TOYEAR = SOURCE.TOYEAR

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT 
         VALUES (SOURCE.MEMBERID, SOURCE.PAGEID, SOURCE.COMPANYID,
                 SOURCE.DESIGNATIONID, SOURCE.LOCATIONID, 
                 SOURCE.FROMDAY, SOURCE.FROMMONTH, SOURCE.FROMYEAR,
                 SOURCE.TODAY, SOURCE.TOMONTH, SOURCE.TOYEAR,
                 SOURCE.[DESCRIPTION], SOURCE.[ISCURRENT], 
                 SOURCE.ENTRYDATE)

    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, $ACTION INTO @TEMPTABLE;

    SELECT ID FROM @TEMPTABLE
END
```

Error shown in the following lines

1. **TARGET.FROMDAY= SOURCE.FROMDAY**
2. **TARGET.TODAY=SOURCE.TODAY**
3. **SOURCE.FROMDAY**
4. **SOURCE.TODAY**

Comment: What;'s the table definition? Which column did you add?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @Richard I have added newly "FromDay" & Today.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you

Comment: So, I wonder: what exactly do you pass into @EXPERIENCEDETAILS? My first guess would be that this table variable is lacking the mentioned new columns...

Comment: @Tyron78 I don't have more knowledge about table variable. Do you have any idea, to consider that new two values too.

Comment: Did you add both columns in table type `[PAGE].[EXPERIENCEDETAILS]`?

Comment: @RuslanK you mean in c#? I have added it in my table.

Comment: @MerbinJoe, no I mean in sql server. You have table and table type in dbo with same name.

Comment: @RuslanK Thank you very much I have found and solved, actually this was not created by me and I don't know above table type. But now its ok.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add those columns in table type `[PAGE].[EXPERIENCEDETAILS]` that used in your SP as TVP type.